# Replace comma as separator

Tags: javascript, regex

I am trying to build a Regex to replace commas used as a separator in between normal text.

Different ways I can replace that is valid:

- Space before comma
- Comma is between text and/or numbers, without any space
- Several commas after each other

Example:

```
"This is a text separated with comma, that I try to fix. , It can be split in several ways.,1234321  , I try to make all the examples in one string,,4321,"
```

Results:

- This is a text separated with comma, that I try to fix.
- It can be split in several ways.
- 1234321
- I try to make all the examples in one string
- 
- 4321

This is the code I have so far using Node.js / Javascript:

```
data.replace(/(\S,\S)|( ,)|(,,)|(,([a-z0-9]))/ig,';')
```

---

The answer from @torazaburo work best, except for several commas with space in-between (, , , ,)

```
console.log(str.split(/ +, *|,(?=\w|,|$)/));
```

Comment: What do you want to replace it with?

Comment: Where is the regexp you tried to make? SO is not a code-writing service, you have to start by trying to solve it yourself, and post what you tried that didn't work. Then we'll help you fix it.

Comment: I try to replace it with semicolon.

Comment: @Punnerud: when you tried to replace with a semi-colon, what did you put into the search field? What are using: C#, Python, SQL....?

Comment: I am using Node.js/Javascript, and are replacing all instances with: data.replace(/ ,/g,';')
 (This replaces all commas with a space before, but I am trying to build a more generic regex)

Comment: @Barmar I added the code now. I am almost there, but I have some characters to many.

Comment: You should use a lookahead to match the letter/number after the comma, so you don't lose it when you do the replacement.

Comment: Why do you have `(,,)` twice? And you can combine `([a-z]|[0-9])` into just `[a-z0-9]`.

Comment: The (,,) was a typo, should be (,,,) and I was trying to solve the problem where I can't get the last comma if the multiplum of several commas is three (,,,) or (,,,,,,). Still trying to figure that out. I did not think about using lookahead, I will try that out. Thank you @Barmar!

Comment: Lookbehind is not supported in Javascript, probably why I haven't seen that before.

Comment: What is the desired behavior in the case of commas with spaces in between?

Comment: To split, that way I can join again with ;

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
var str = "This is a text separated with comma, that I try to fix. , It can be split in several ways.,1234321  , I try to make all the examples in one string,,4321,";

console.log(str.split(/ +, *|,(?=\w|,|$)/));
```

This will split on any comma preceded by one or more spaces, no matter what follows (and eat the preceding spaces, and following spaces if any); **or**, any comma followed by an alphanumeric or comma or end-of-string.

There is no easy way with the regexp to get rid of the final empty string in the result, caused by the comma at the very end of the input. You can get rid of that yourself if you don't want it.

To rejoin with semi-colon, add `.join(';')`.

Comment: var str = "some text  ,    ,  ,     more text";

Answer (score 1):

```
data.replace(/\s*,+\s*/g, ';');
```

This will yield:

> This is a text separated with comma;that I try to fix.;It can be split in several ways.;1234321;I try to make all the examples in one string;4321;

There are three parts to this:

1. `\s*`: Match zero or more whitespace characters.
2. `,+`: Match one or more commas.
3. `\s*`: Match zero or more whitespace characters.

If, instead, you want to replace any number of consecutive commas with a single semi-colon:

```
data.replace(/,+/g, ';');
```

Honestly, I'm not sure I understood your requirements. If I did misunderstand, please provide the output string you're expecting.